# Samba file sharing is not working!

Tags: ubuntu, samba

Here is my current Configuration:

I added this line on my /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[share]
comment = Samba Server
browsable = yes
path = /srv/share/samba
guest ok = yes
read only =  no
create mask = 0755
```

This is my current nmbd.service status

```
● nmbd.service - LSB: start Samba NetBIOS nameserver (nmbd)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nmbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sab 2017-03-04 17:39:49 WIB; 4s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 588 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/nmbd stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 603 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nmbd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nmbd.service
           └─623 /usr/sbin/nmbd -D
```

This is my current smbd.service status

```
● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sab 2017-03-04 17:41:37 WIB; 5s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 631 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/smbd stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 643 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/smbd.service
           ├─663 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
           ├─664 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
           └─666 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
```

!!!HERE IS THE ERROR!!!

When i executed: `sytemctl start samba.service`

```
Failed to start samba.service: Unit samba.service is masked.
```

!!!HERE IS MY CURRENT SAMBA.SERVICE STATUS!!!

```
● samba.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `service smbd restart`

Comment: @Cyber_Star: your command has the same outcome by using `systemctl start smbd.service`.

It is still not solving the  problem, and `samba.service` is failed to load.

Comment: Try to unmask the service first with `systemctl unmask samba.service`. Then do a `systemct restart samba.service`.

Comment: What did you change in the config file?

Comment: @Thomas: after i did what you suggested, it still got this type of error
[`Failed to restart samba.service: Unit samba.service is masked.`]

Comment: @Cyber_Star, i did not change, but i added the line above and that was it. i put those lines at the very end section. the only thing did not work was `samba.service`. I thought i correctly configured the rest.

the line at `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

`[share]
comment = Samba Server
browsable = yes
path = /srv/share/samba
guest ok = yes
read only =  no
create mask = 0755`

Answer (score 0):

Just installed `samba` in a Ubuntu 16.04 VM and it turns out to be a mess concerning the start scripts.

After investigating the samba starter methods, I think the most sane method would be to use the `systemd` unitfiles `smbd` and `nmbd`.

There are `systemd`, `upstart` and SysV methods to start the services.

- `upstart` seems just to be disabled by default in Ubuntu 16.04
- SysV seems to work, but it's not possible to make them autostart with `update-rc.d`, since those are intended to be managed by `systemd` SysV compatibility generator
- `systemd` commands are the way to go to make use of the SysV scripts

So best would be to just use the commands as follows to start/stop/restart the services.

```
systemctl [start|stop|restart] smbd
systemctl [start|stop|restart] nmbd
```

To make them autostart at boot.

```
systemctl enable smbd
systemctl enable nmbd
```

Comment: I finally got it working. but still when i tried to run `samba.service` or `samba`, it gives masked error. I just ignore the error it is worked. But i dont know what `samba.service` gives any difference still. I changed a bit on [share] section to be like this http://termbin.com/h1wu.